# NullPointerException in InitialContext

Tags: glassfish, client, ejb, remoteobject

NullPointerException in InitialContext

```
private void connect() {
 try {
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
    IServerBean serverBean = (IServerBean)ctx.
       lookup("java:global/applicationserver/ServerBean!
       com.test.applicationserver.IServerBean");
 } catch (NamingException  e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
   }
}
```

I got this exception when try to execute client application through console `java -cp cleint-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.test.client.EJBClient`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.<init>(SerialContext.java:276)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.<init>(SerialContext.java:335)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory.createInitialContext
(SerialInitContextFactory.java:358)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory.getInitialContext
(SerialInitContextFactory.java:353)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory.getInitialContext
(SerialInitContextFactory.java:69)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.test.client.EJBClient.connect(EJBClient.java:33)
at com.test.client.EJBClient.main(EJBClient.java:61)
```

This application connecting to remote EJB module. 
But when I try to execute it in Eclipse, all's gone fine.
My configuration:

- Java SE 1.7
- GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5)
- Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: Juno Service Release
  1 Build id: 20121004-1855

Maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\lib\tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.appclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>gf-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with this solution:

Adding this libraries to folder with application:

- glassfish-embedded-all-3.1.1.jar hk2-core-1.6.9.jar
- internal-api-3.1.2.2.jar
- common-util-3.1.2.2.jar
- glassfish-corba-internal-api-3.2.0-b005.jar
- glassfish-naming-3.1.2.2.jar

And when running application, add this libraries to classpath:

`java -cp glassfish-embedded.jar;hk2-core.jar;internal-api.jar;common-util.jar;glassfish-corba-internal-api.jar;glassfish-naming.jar;cleintconsole-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.test.client.EJBClient`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Resolved :
You must add gf-client.jar and appserv-rt.jar not only in classpath of your project but also in runtime (With Eclipse, See Run As > Run configurations > Classpath > Add jars ) .